# Adding a title attribute to svg:g element in D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js, treemap

I'm building an app with D3.js that displays a data in a tree-map. Ideally what I would like to is give the tree-map a tool-tip to display more info on each node of the tree-map. The tree-map is fed data from a .JSON file.

I am currently working with the jquery plug-in `Poshy Tip` where I can pass this info through the `title=` attribute. I know I need to somehow add the title attribute to the svg:g element in the tree-map but I can't figure out where I set each nodes title attr.

Heres the beginning of my script where I make all my declarations etc...

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
.size([h, w - 160]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
.projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h)
.append("svg:g")
.attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

d3.json("test.json", function(json) {
  json.x0 = 800;
  json.y0 = 0;
  update(root = json);
});
```

Here is how I am using `poshytip()` in the head

```
$(function(){
  $('node').poshytip({slide: false, followCursor: true, alignTo: 'cursor', 
    showTimeout: 0, hideTimeout: 0, alignX: 'center', alignY: 'inner-bottom',
    className: 'tip-twitter'});
}
```

Pretty much I just want to be able to "mouseover" the individual items in the interactive tree-map and get a tooltip to pop-up.. but i havent had any luck. How can I set each item to have a specific Id.. do I do that in the .JSON file? Is there an easier way to do this? Am I going about this in the wrong manner? Any help would be great.

Comment: Where is the code that is actually drawing the tree?  It will have a select and a data option.  You should be able to just add .attr('title', "My Title").

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h);

var yourGElement = vis.append("svg:g").attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

yourGElement.append("svg:title").text("Your tooltip info");
```

Comment: Note, however, that this won't work in the update case.  If your code needs to work a 2nd time around with new data, you will need to remove and append the title again, or just change its text.

Answer (score 5):

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; })
      .append("svg:title")
          .text(function(d){return "Name:"+d.Name+"\nAge:"+d.age;});
```

`SVG` dynamically append title attribute. Once we move mouse over the circle it shows the Name, Age in small pop up. Name, age must be specified in `test.json`.

Comment: Is there a way to customize this title? E.g.: change the text and background color?